# Have a HDLC health insurance with a $4000 benefit going into a HSA. Just found out I am not eligible for the HSA. How to rectify

Tags: united-states, income-tax, hsa, medicare

Did not know I was not eligible for HSA as I have had Medicare for several years. The $4000 dollars the company put into the account has been used as my wife had major surgery. There is a $3000 deductible before full coverage kicks in. How can I clear this up prior to doing income tax. Any chance of paying income taxes on the $4000 and have the HSA rolled back??

Comment: Was the $4000 all contributed in this year, or did some of it come from previous years?

Comment: So you have a high deductible medical insurance policy, and medicare?